# Will it be $\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}$ or $\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}$?

Tags: vectors

[image]

The resultant of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ is $\vec{AD}$. Now, which of the following is correct?

$$\vec{AB}+\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}\tag{1}$$

$$\vec{AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec{AD}\tag{2}$$

I think $(1)$ is correct.

Comment: Crossposted to [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/700280/260477)

Comment: @Wuestenfux If you post this comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Answer accepted in [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/700281/260477).

Comment: You've successively, as a matter of default, cross-posted over ten Questions to both the Mathematics and Physics sites. Your [previous Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700098/how-to-replace-these-two-forces-with-one-force#comment1566992_700098) was cross-posted to three sites. Please just post to the most appropriate site, and [cross-post only as a last resort](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting) (after at least a few days).